# Customise the Ubuntu server installer

Tags: server, customization, autoinstall

We already use autoinstall files to automate our Ubuntu Server install. But as we're also installing our own software on the first boot, we need a way to aks the user for input.

Is there a way to customise the Ubuntu server text based installer to ask for user input?

Is there a way to ask for user input without requiring the user to login first?